# Spock: test name and outcome in setup() cleanup() methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am wondering if it is possible to make the following data available in a Spock test's lifecycle methods:

- test name in the setup() method
- test name and test outcome in the cleanup() method

The reason I am asking is that I would like send these metadata to a data sink without the need to touch each and every test.

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Try `this.specificationContext.iterationInfo.name` in `setup()`. Not sure if it works. In general `specificationContext` is the place where I'd be looking for such data.

Comment: Opal's solutions works like a charm! Good point Opal

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

Try `this.specificationContext.iterationInfo.name` in `setup()`. Not sure if it works. In general `specificationContext` is the place where I'd be looking for such data.

Answer (score 2):

Update from Opal's answer:

It is now (Spock 1.1) `specificationContext.currentIteration.name`

For the record, you could also use

```
@Rule
TestName testName = new org.junit.rules.TestName()
...
println "name: $testName.methodName"
```

... but there seems no point.

For the other question, getting the outcome: I couldn't find a way of getting this from Spock's `SpecificationContext`.

I took a quick look at `org.junit.rules.TestWatcher` ... but with Spock this seemed unable to detect a failed test.